# jQuery ajax callback function stop after append received data and received jquery script dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have two problems with jQuery ajax call back. 
I have following code of jQuery ajax call:

```
                  <div id="newpages"></div>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                  <!--
                    var page = 1;
                    var max_pages_number = <?php echo $max_pages_number; ?>;
                      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        jQuery("#registry_show_more").click(function(){
                          if(page < max_pages_number) {
                              jQuery.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                                    data: {
                                      action: 'registry_paggination',
                                      page: page+1,
                                      plusid: 18,  
                                      page_size: <?php echo $page_size; ?>,
                                      category: <?php echo $kategoria; ?>,
                                      filtr: '<?php echo $filtr; ?>',     
                                      access: <?php echo $access; ?>,
                                    },
                                    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                                      page++;
                                      if(page >= max_pages_number) {
                                        jQuery("#registry_show_more").hide();
                                      }
                                      if(data) {
                                        alert('a');
                                        jQuery("#newpages").append(jQuery("#newpages").html() +data);
                                        alert('b');
                                      }
                                    },
                                    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){}
                                });
                              }
                           });
                        });
                  //-->
                  </script>
                  <div style="display: block;" id="registry_show_more">
                    <a class="w-blog-entry-more g-btn type_default size_small">WCZYTAJ WIĘCEJ</a>
                  </div>
```

First problem. After received data in ajax callback first alert('a') shows, then data is appended to div with id="newpages". But second alert('b') dont shows.

Second problem. In ajax.php file i have part of code like this:

```
                                        <script type="text/javascript">                                         
                                        <!-- plus
                      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        jQuery("#bp<?php echo $row->registry_id; ?>").click(function(){
                          if(!jQuery.cookie('regvote<?php echo $row->registry_id; ?>')) {
                              jQuery.cookie('regvote<?php echo $row->registry_id; ?>','+', { expires: 1 });
                              jQuery.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                                    data: {
                                      action: 'registryVote',
                                      plusid: <?php echo $row->registry_id; ?>,
                                    },
                                    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                                      jQuery("#vc<?php echo $row->registry_id; ?>").html(data);
                                    },
                                    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){}
                                });
                              }
                           });
                        });
                      //-->
                                        </script>

                                    <div class="post twc-post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry w-blog-entry">

                                          <div id="votepanel<?php echo $row->registry_id; ?>" style="width: 35px; float: left;">
                                            <a style="cursor:pointer; cursor:hand" id="bp<?php echo $row->registry_id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" style="cursor: hand !important; color: #bd2029; font-size: 32px;"></i></a>
                                            <h6 id="vc<?php echo $row->registry_id; ?>" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"><?php echo number_format((double)$row->value,1); ?></h6>
                                           <a style="cursor:pointer; cursor:hand" id="bm<?php echo $row->registry_id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" style="color: #bd2029; font-size: 22px;"></i></a>
                  </div>

                                        <script type="text/javascript">                                         
                                        <!-- minus
                      //jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        jQuery("#bm<?php echo $row->registry_id; ?>").click(function(){
                          if(!jQuery.cookie('regvote<?php echo $row->registry_id; ?>')) {
                              jQuery.cookie('regvote<?php echo $row->registry_id; ?>','-', { expires: 1 });
                              jQuery.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                                    data: {
                                      action: 'registryVote',
                                      minusid: <?php echo $row->registry_id; ?>,
                                    },
                                    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                                      jQuery("#vc<?php echo $row->registry_id; ?>").html(data);
                                    },
                                    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){}
                                });
                              }
                            });
                       // });
                      //-->
                                        </script>
```

And scripts MINUS and PLUS don't work when i append them to div "newpages". All elements are showed but scripts don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure, but I think the first problem is cause because you cant use append to append an html Text. You can append elements but directly html is not a good idea I think. Try using `jQuery("#newpages").html(jQuery("#newpages").html() + data);` instead

About the second problem as far as I understand you are appending those scripts into a file after a call ? Isnt the call after the Document.Ready have already passed ? You append the scripts correctly but the scripts are executing after document.ready which have passed already ? Sorry if I havent understood the chronololy correctly.